# Push to array after each iteration to make one large array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have a scenario where I have an async request that is pushing data to a child react component. When I log in the "data" in the component, I get back multiple arrays one by one by one...Ideally I would like to avoid rewriting the request in the parent component and just push each array iteration to one large array. Is this possible?

What I currently get

```
[
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 6:25 AM",       
    },
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 12:45 PM",       
    }
 ]

 [
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 6:25 AM",       
    },
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 12:45 PM",       
    },
    {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 2:00 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 9:00 PM",       
     },
 ]

 [
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 6:25 AM",       
    },
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 12:45 PM",       
    },
    {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 2:00 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 9:00 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 5:20 AM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 12:45 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 1:00 PM",       
     },
 ]

 [
    {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 2:00 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 9:00 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 5:20 AM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 12:45 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 1:00 PM",       
     },
 ]

 ....
```

My desired result would be:

```
[
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 6:25 AM",       
    },
    {
       "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 12:45 PM",       
    },
    {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 6:25 AM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 12:45 PM",       
     },
     {
         "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 2:00 PM",       
      },
      {
         "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 9:00 PM",       
      },
      {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 6:25 AM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 12:45 PM",       
     },
     {
         "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 2:00 PM",       
      },
      {
         "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 9:00 PM",       
      },
      {
         "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 5:20 AM",       
      },
      {
         "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 12:45 PM",       
      },
      {
         "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 1:00 PM",       
      },
      {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 2:00 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Thu, 05/12, 9:00 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 5:20 AM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 12:45 PM",       
     },
     {
        "dates":"Aired on 05/11/22, 1:00 PM",       
     }
 ]
```

This results in an infinite loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (data[0]) data.push(data)
   console.log(data[i])
}
```

Screenshot of console log in child component.
[image]

Comment: What's the structure of the stairs? Is it a big multi-dimensional array of multiple status of objects?

Comment: Posted a screenshot of the console log

Comment: Put all the arrays inside a big array, then `bigArray.flatMap(i => i)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you collect all arrays in one large array (e.g. `const arr = [];` to define the large array, then `arr.push(incomingArray);` whenever you get one of the arrays):

With modern JS runtimes, you can use `Array.flatMap`:

```js
const arr = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]];
console.log(arr.flatMap(entry => entry));
```

With older ones, you can build your own flatmap implementation using `reduce` quite easily:

```js
const arr = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]];
console.log(arr.reduce((aggregated, entry)=> [...aggregated, ...entry]));
```

---

Update: full example:

```js
const collectionArray = [];

function onArrayArrived(arr) {
    collectionArray.push(arr);
}

function getFlattenedCollectionArray() {
   return collectionArray.flatMap(entry => entry);
}

onArrayArrived(["a", "b"]);
onArrayArrived(["c", "d"]);
onArrayArrived(["e", "f"]);

console.log(getFlattenedCollectionArray());
```

Comment: Still no dice. Having an async request in my parent is still resulting in separate arrays